# How do I deal with flags

Tags: support

So, the SE UI started bringing active flags to my attention, and I'm unsure how to handle them.

One of the flagged answers was to the qestion [How to configure proxy setting in Pluggable Transport Bundle?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/how-to-configure-proxy-setting-in-pluggable-transport-bundle).

The answer is quite short, and not of high quality:

> You can't set the proxy in PTBB, just try TBB without pluggable

But it's also not wrong (true, it's missing the full stop at the end, but that's an easy fix :).

So, what do I do about those flags?  Do I re-raise them to the moderators saying this is a poor answer?  I don't think it should get deleted.  Do I say I disagree with the flag?

Comment: Personally, in cases like this I like to link to the "[How to write a good answer](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" article in the help center, and ask the user to improve their answer. If they don't, I eventually just submit an edit (or if it's in some way negative or taking away from the quality of the question, remove it)

Answer (score 4):

Sam's comment is correct.

In cases like that it's best to leave a comment in the first instance, asking for it to be improved, and possibly suggesting improvements to be made, if any are obvious.

Comment: It's also worth clarifying that 2k+ users can also cast a flag of their own to either agree with or disagree with the existing flags. This might be helpful to the moderators to see more than one person flagging a post.